# Let $H \le G$, when does there exists normal complements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H \le G$, if $H$ is normal in $G$ and $(|H|, |G/H|) = 1$, then according to the famous [Schur-Zassenhaus-Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem) we can find a complement in $G$ for $H$. This need not be normal. Now my question:

Are there any sufficient conditions to guarantee that a complement for $H \le G$ is normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be complement of $H$,  $H$ normalize $K$ if and only if $K$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: yes thanks, proof is quite simple too, let $H$ normalize $K$ and if $g = hk$, then $K^g = (K^h)^k = K^k = K$. The other direction is obvious.

Comment: yeah exactly this.

Comment: and let me note, $H \cap K = \{1\}$ was not used, so it holds more generally for $G = AB$: $$A ~\mbox{ normalises } ~ B \quad \mbox{iff} \quad B \unlhd G.$$